# Subclassing titleLabel of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

Have someone idea or example how can I subclass titleLabel of `UIButton`? I want to change the text behavior of my text Button during different controlState. I want if the button is highlighted then only the text border should be visualised.

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: You should subclass `UIButton`

Comment: I have subclassed UIButton, the problem the behavior how to change the border of the text should be achieved in drawtextinRect. But i don´t know how can i call this method during different state of the button ?

Comment: Subclassing `UIButton` is almost always a bad idea. Subclass `UIControl` instead.

Comment: can you give some example how to achieve it with subclassing UIControl?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `UIButton` ,in `.h`,you can have a custom `UILabel` as the `titleLabel` of `UIButton`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *nameLabel;
```

If you want to call some method during different state of the `UIButton`, you can rewrite the method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    self.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    self.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

I write a simple code to show how to custom a `UIButton` :

[a simple code to show how to custom a UIButton](https://github.com/ChenYilong/CYLBusinessCardButton)

Comment: Thank Stevechen, but my problem is drawTextInRect Method of UILabel. When the button is highleighted should only the border´s text of the label displayed. Else the text should normally showed.

Comment: drawtextinrect method (where i can make my text shown only its border) is called when the Label is initialized. That is why i can handle different States of the button

Comment: If you have other idea to solve my problem it will be very nice

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the custom UIButton.
2. Create the UILabel
3. Use CALayer to draw the border around the UILabel.
4. Add the UILabel as subview of UIButton.

Please refer the below code which is doing the same. Add the border for the respective state of the button.

```
-(void)addBorderToButtonLabel
{
    CGRect labelRect = self.sampleButton.bounds;
    labelRect.origin.x = 10;
    labelRect.origin.y = 5;
    labelRect.size.width -= 10 *2;
    labelRect.size.height -= 5 * 2;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
    label.text = @"My Sample";
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    label.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;

    [self.sampleButton addSubview:label];
}
```

Comment: Border of the text of the Label not Label